# Azure Elastic Job - a stored procedure does not run on the target database

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, sql-server-agent

**The target group NPBlue contains 3 databases**

```
NPBlue  882E2367-93C0-46CC-A4ED-90AE5F2860EB    Include SqlDatabase 69B479D8-34FA-48A6-9A3D-6B302864B9AD    NULL    NULL    NULL    x-database-weu.database.windows.net x1-test NULL    NULL
NPBlue  882E2367-93C0-46CC-A4ED-90AE5F2860EB    Include SqlDatabase 42875252-9521-4A50-903D-D57FAB836C96    NULL    NULL    NULL    x-database-weu.database.windows.net x2-dev  NULL    NULL
NPBlue  882E2367-93C0-46CC-A4ED-90AE5F2860EB    Include SqlDatabase 83A931C4-C356-418C-AE51-EB973EC2FACF    NULL    NULL    NULL    x-database-weu.database.windows.net x3-qa   NULL    NULL
```

**A job that runs once a day**

```
DECLARE @JobName NVARCHAR(128) = N'[NPBlue] Deleting inactive users and related data';
DECLARE @JobDescription NVARCHAR(512) = N'This job will run daily starting at 23:30';
DECLARE @Enabled BIT = 1;
DECLARE @ScheduleIntercalType NVARCHAR(50) = N'Days';
DECLARE @ScheduleIntervalCount INT = 1;
DECLARE @ScheduleStart DATETIME2 = N'20230101 23:30';

EXEC jobs.sp_add_job @job_name = @JobName,
@description = @JobDescription,
@enabled = @Enabled,
@schedule_interval_type = @ScheduleIntercalType,
@schedule_interval_count = @ScheduleIntervalCount,
@schedule_start_time = @ScheduleStart
```

**Job step for previous job**

The following stored procedure is executed on the target databases - this function only adds its full name according to the schema.

```
DECLARE @JobName NVARCHAR(128) = N'[NPBlue] Deleting inactive users and related data';
DECLARE @JobStepName NVARCHAR(128) = N'Execute stored procedure';
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
DECLARE @procedure_name NVARCHAR(100) = ‘’xxx_delete_inactive_users'';
DECLARE @schema_name NVARCHAR(100);

SELECT @schema_name = SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE name = @procedure_name;

DECLARE @dynamic_sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(@procedure_name);

EXEC sp_executesql @dynamic_sql;
';
DECLARE @CredentialName NVARCHAR(128) = N'job_credential';
DECLARE @TargetGroupName NVARCHAR(128) = N'NPBlue';
DECLARE @retryAttempts INT = 0;

EXEC jobs.sp_add_jobstep @job_name = @JobName,
@step_name = @JobStepName,
@command = @Command,
@credential_name = @CredentialName,
@target_group_name = @TargetGroupName,
@retry_attempts = @retryAttempts;
```

In short I run `EXEC sp_executesql [x1-test].[xxx_delete_inactive_users]` etc.

According to the log and the portal it is correctly started and completed, but on the target database this is not the case - the data that should be deleted are still there.

last_message :

```
Step 1 succeeded execution on target (server ‘xxx.database.windows.net', database ‘x1-test').
Step 1 succeeded.
Job execution succeeded.
```

Manual execution of the procedure on the target database works.